# PHP: faster cURL execution

Tags: php, design-patterns, curl, singleton

I have an application that uses cURL to grab the contents of several websites. I'd like to optimize this somehow. Would it be possible to implement a singleton design pattern and somehow feed curl the URLs I need contents for at certain intervals -- such that I only instantiate it once?

Right now, I setup and destroy connections for each call. Sample code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i suggest you to use some framework for loading cURL module as a component. I use yii framework http://www.yiiframework.com/ . I use cURL extension provided by yii community. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/curl

Comment: @brainless - I'm already using CodeIgniter. I'll look into it and see if I can implement something like you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like unnecessary micro-optimization to me. You'll save a fraction of a microsecond for a process that has to go across the internet to grab a hunk of data from a resource that's already out of your control. If you're simply trying to get the process to run faster, maybe try running multiple downloads in parallel.

Edit: And/or make sure your curl supports compressed content.

Comment: I am already handling all encoding. Also, I am already using cURL's curl_multi_exec.

Comment: Great, then I think you've done what you can. The effort required to pool connection handles for remote web page downloads is well beyond the point of diminishing returns.

Answer (score 1):

A number of possible solutions come to mind. The easiest one is probably to build in some kind of caching mechanism. Store the response on disk, and use that until it becomes stale, then perform a new request to update the cache. That alone should vastly improve your performance. Another way of implementing this would be to use a caching proxy server.

Another option is to simply create a cronjob with wget fetching the needed content every couple of minutes and storing the result on disk. Then just access that content from your application. That way, you'll never have to wait for a request to finish.

Comment: Caching remote resources is the by far biggest performance improvement you'll get (even if you only cache in small intervals)

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the remote data, but the connection handle used to get it.

Comment: caching is not a problem I am trying to solve. Is wget faster that cURL? I am already using cron to call a method that does the cURL operations. The URLs I need to collect data from come from my database + some implemented logic to determine exactly which URLs I am interested in. If wget is faster than cURL, I'm not sure how to pass these URLs to it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use [curl multi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) to have requests run in parallel. Look at the example on that page.

As a side note: this has nothing to do with singleton or design patterns. While static allows you to keep a persistent application state between requests in Java, this is not possible in PHP.

Comment: I am already using curl_multi_exec. It allows me to retrieve content in parallel. I'm trying to further optimize this.

As for singleton, I was thinking of this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php